Generalized Forces in Euler-Lagrange Equation
I am looking for a reference proving that the generalized forces in the Euler-Lagrange equation is equivalent to the torque exerted by the revolute joints / forces exerted by the prismatic joints. It would be a plus if it is written in the language of modern geometry (manifolds, vector bundles, ...)!

In The Theoretical Minimum by Leonard Susskind and George Hrabovsky, chapter 6 derives the Euler-Lagrange equation from the Principle of Least Action. Using generalized coordinates, of course. Because of that generality, you can write down the Lagrangian using any convenient coordinates, and even manipulate the resulting mechanics according to some other coordinate system. In particular, it sees pretty clear that the torques and forces that you mention are "merely" special cases of the general treatment. Doesn't that establish that they are equivalent for your purposes? I guess I am missing how modern geometry would help.
